# Cannot reach bind dns in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, dns, bind, microk8s

I am trying to install a DNS Server inside a local Kubernetes cluster using microK8S, but I cannot reach DNS.

Here deployments script:

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: bind
  labels:
    app: bind
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bind
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bind
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: bind
          image: sameersbn/bind
          env:
            - name: ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: "toto"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data
              name: data
          ports:
            - containerPort: 53
              protocol: UDP
            - containerPort: 53
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 10000
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bind-dns
  labels:
    name: bind-dns
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: dns
      port: 53
      targetPort: 53
      protocol: UDP
    - name: dns-tcp
      port: 53
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 53
  selector:
    name: bind
```

service is expose with ip

```
bind-dns        LoadBalancer   10.152.183.144   <pending>     53/UDP,53/TCP     11m
```

When I ssh into bind pod it works

```
host www.google.com 0.0.0.0
Using domain server:
Name: 0.0.0.0
Address: 0.0.0.0#53
Aliases: 

www.google.com has address 172.217.13.132
www.google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4020:805::2004
```

But outside container it does not

```
host www.google.com 10.152.183.144
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

What is wrong ? Why I cannot reach server ?

Answer (score 1):

Service resource `spec.selector` need to specify pod `spec.metadata.labels`.
So I think you need to change the Service resource of the yaml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bind-dns
  labels:
    name: bind-dns
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: dns
      port: 53
      targetPort: 53
      protocol: UDP
    - name: dns-tcp
      port: 53
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 53
  selector:
    app: bind # changed
```